# How do you make the bottom panel in Okular disappear?

Tags: settings, okular

The bottom bar of Okular spans the whole screen and only has the page count on it.  There are no settings to make it disappear.  How do you hide/delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the bottom bar go away, open the file `~/.kde/share/config/okularpartrc` and under the section that says `[Main View]` add the following line:

```
ShowBottomBar=false
```

Answer (score 1):

From the menu bar toggle *Settings* -> *Show Page Bar*.

For me the folder `~/.kde/` did not exist however  `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/okular` exists. It is not required though.

[image]

This is Okular version 1.9.3 .